# python: displaying help documents

Tags: python, emacs, ipython, python-mode

I am running python-mode with iPython in emacs. Especially with numpy packages, when I type

```
[1]: help(numpy.array)
```

or anything similar in the interactive buffer, pages and pages of documentation are printed in the buffer, making it difficult to search through the other material printed in the buffer. Is there a better way to go about this? In R, you can display help pages in a web browser (the documents are on local HD) very easily by changing `options(help_type="html")`, and there the document is formatted nicely also. Is there anything like this in Python, or what do you do? I don't always have an internet connection so I'd like a local HD solution please.

Answer (score 2):

if you use ipython alone (not inside emacs) it should paginate the text out of the box.
if not, probably the environment variable PAGER has been overwritten: se it to "less" and it should work

For the bash shell, add to your ~/.bashrc these lines:

```
export PAGER=less
export LESS=-r
```

if you want html help you may consider [pydoc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pydoc.html#module-pydoc)

```
import pydoc
pydoc.apropos('numpy.array')
```

Answer (score 1):

[`pydoc`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pydoc.html) is probably what you are looking for.

You can have `pydoc` run its own web server to display documentation with the `-p` flag (which takes a port number like `1234`). For me, it displays documentation for all of the modules in my `PYTHONPATH`, which is very convenient.

Comment: Thanks, I did `!pydoc -p 1234 &` in iPython buffer, but help still prints in same buffer

Comment: @crippledlambda Yes, there's (currently) no way to change that. You can search through the local documentation in the browser.

Comment: Isn't the `pydoc -p` command supposed to open the local documentation in the browser, or I'm misunderstanding what it's supposed to do?